# JavaScript to check field for same value and if so, continue to calculation total

Tags: javascript, pdf

Not getting a Total BT Credit sum, when BookIn # matches. Please see attached screenshot.

[image]

But, I need for it to also check the BookIn # field and if matches previous BookIn # file field, ignore and continue with Total BT Credit.

JavaScript that checks BookIn # field, if blank then sum all the rows to Total BT Credit field. This works with the current code.

```
//************ add global script for calculation *******************/
var holderCnt = 0;
var tltCredit = 0;
var bookInNbr = "";

for ( var ii = 1; ii < 31; ii ++)
{
    var bookIn = this.getField("BookIn " + ii).valueAsString;
    var credit = parseInt(this.getField("BT Days Credit" + ii).value);

    if (ii == 1)
    {
        holderCnt = ii;
        bookInNbr = bookIn;
        tltCredit = credit;
        continue;
    }

    if (ii > 1 && (bookIn == "" || bookIn == bookInNbr))
    {
        tltCredit += credit;
        continue;
    }

    this.getField("Total BT Credit" + holderCnt).value = tltCredit;
    // reset values
    holderCnt = ii;
    bookInNbr = bookIn;
    tltCredit = credit;
}
//************ end *******************/
```

Gives a Total BT Credit amount even when BookIN # matches.

Comment: Got sample input?

Comment: This looks like it might be a script for Google Sheets or some kind of online spreadsheet application? If so, please [edit] your question and add the appropriate tag and/or text to tell people what that is.

Comment: Not Google Sheets, but PDF form. Can I upload the PDF form, it has sample data?

Comment: You're getting and setting the field values correctly (I think based on how I assume you are naming your fields. I'm not sure about the logic though. Can you post a version of the PDF with the name and case numbers blank so I can test it with your actual field names?

Comment: Do I attached as an image? I don't see an option for uploading a file.